# Mapserver GetLegendGraphic via expression

Tags: mapserver, legend, getlegendgraphic

I am trying around this for a while now. But can't find any answer. So I try it here.

**What do I have:**

Mapserver 7.0.6

**What do I want:**

Obtaining a single legend graphic for a class without text and in custom width/heigth **by passing the value evaluated in the class**.

Let me describe it a little more with examples:

Lets say we have a **CLASS** defined in a mapfile with the **NAME "Test Name"** which matches the **EXPRESSION "100"**. I can access this simply by the following URL:

`test.mapserv?width=72&height=36&layer=test&version=1.1.1&service=WMS&format=image/png&request=GetLegendGraphic&rule=Test Name`

I will get the resulting image as I expect. But for the reason of encoding issues and because I trust the numbers more than prosa text I want to use the expression instead. My dream would be something like this:

`test.mapserv?width=72&height=36&layer=test&version=1.1.1&service=WMS&format=image/png&request=GetLegendGraphic&rule=100`

For sure: This won't work. I tried several other stuff. I was passing a SLD to filter the legend by the **EXPRESSION** but this answers with the legendimage + the legend text like the following:

[image]

This is explicitly not what I want. I only want the simple icon. And I really want to do it via URL of OGC service to stay as close as possible to well known standards.

So now my hope is to find somebody out there who is able to show me a way to achieve this.